# How do I scan memory for an array of hex values in LLDB?

Tags: debugging, lldb

I want to find N (for example, 16) bytes of hex in memory. In gdb, I simply do:

```
find /b memrange_start, memrange_end, 0x00, 0x01, 0x02, 0x03, 0x04, 0x05, 0x06, 0x07, 0x08, 0x09, 0x0a, 0x0b, 0x0c, 0x0d, 0x0e, 0x0f
```

And it works flawlessly. What's the equivalent in lldb? I tried:

```
(lldb) me find -e "0x01 0x02 0x03" -- 0x00000001050e8000 0x00000001050e9000
```

But it just looks for the last byte (0x03). String search using the -s parameter and "\x00\x01\x02\x03(...)\x0f" does not work either. Furthermore, when I tried various combinations, I stumbled upon this error:

```
(lldb) me find -e "{0x01, 0x02}" 0x7fffbe6abfc6 0x7fffbe6abfcf
error: result size larger than 8 bytes. pass a string instead
```

Please don't tell me I'm limited to 8 bytes with "-e" :( Did I miss some easy way to scan for the virtual address of 16 bytes of hex in memory?

Comment: There's a `lldb` bug mentioned in https://stackoverflow.com/a/33114721/5329717 - using special formatting  (e.g. `\x0 \255`) is impossible neither for `me f -e` nor `me f -s`. Ironically an open source fork of `lldb` exists having it fixed 3 years ago.